# want use only getTax method from avalara api

Tags: api, wsdl, mule, mule-studio, avalara

There are multiple elements like  but I want to use only GetTax out of those and hide all other element methods. is there any method to implement it? using proxy or somehow, please suggest. I am new to mule and SOAP services

Comment: Have you read the Mule documentation on [consuming web services](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer)? That would be a good place to start. If you have already read the docs, then  it would be a good idea to post a more specific question with a sample of your flow logic.

Comment: Hey Danw,
thanks for the reply, the thing is I have a WSDL for the AVALARA API but i don't want the source to hit it directly. I want to put some proxy or create a another WSDL at some another location so that the end user cannot directly use the main AVALARA WSDL. In RESTFUL API we can do this easily by deploying the proxy but in SOAP I need to user CXF but there are many part in CXF like service proxy, JAX-WS, client proxy that makes me confused.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, essentially it is: `Client -> Mule Proxy -> Avalara API`. I appreciate that you may not fully understand how CXF work from a Mule angle but you should read the documentation first, attempt to make it work and then post a more specific question. Try the Mule documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/proxying-your-api) and [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/proxying-web-services-with-cxf).